# How to extract string in pandas with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe:

swimming(4)
1   4                               hiking   (1 )
2   2                               running ( 12 )
3   5                               fishing( 2 )

```
|     |  sid  | Hobby (times per month) |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  0  |   3   |      swimming(4)        |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  1  |   4   |      hiking  (1 )       |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  2  |   2   |      running ( 12 )     |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  3  |   5   |      fishing ( 2 )      |
```

How to extract strings by removing the brackets in the second column as:

```
|     |  sid  | Hobby (times per month) |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  0  |   3   |        swimming         |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  1  |   4   |        hiking           |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  2  |   2   |        running          |
|-----+-------+-------------------------|
|  3  |   5   |        fishing          |
```

Comment: Have a look at apply (or was it map?)

Comment: If it is always the structure `hobby_xyz (n_times)` then you can split the string on `(` and just keep the first element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want for example, `swimming(4)` to be changed to `swimming`, you can use below regex:

```
^([\w]+)[\s]*\([\s]*[\d]*[\s]*\)[\s]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sTO1Q9/1

Test Cases:

```
swimming(4)
hiking   (1 )
running ( 12 )
fishing( 2 )
hiking(1)
```

Match:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-11    `swimming(4)`
Group 1.    0-8 `swimming`
Match 2
Full match  12-25   `hiking   (1 )`
Group 1.    12-18   `hiking`
Match 3
Full match  26-40   `running ( 12 )`
Group 1.    26-33   `running`
Match 4
Full match  41-53   `fishing( 2 )`
Group 1.    41-48   `fishing`
Match 5
Full match  54-64   `hiking(1) `
Group 1.    54-60   `hiking`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'str' method to match the string in pandas

```
df.columns = ['sid','Hobby']
df.Hobby = df.Hobby.str.extract(r'(\w*)')
```

Answer (score 0):

to implement the regex in pandas you can use pandas.apply():

```
import re

def remove_brackets(string):
    part = regexp_matcher.findall(string)
    if not part:
        return string
    return part[0]

regexp_matcher = re.compile(r'^([\w]+)[\s]*\([\s]*[\d]*[\s]*\)[\s]*$')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['string'] = ['swimming(4)', 'swimming(4)', 'swimming(4)']    
df['new_string'] = df['string'].apply(remove_brackets)
```